# Auto-start a service after install in android

Tags: android

I am new to android development am wondering if it's possible to start a background service right after install. At the moment the apk is built through android studio and I usually install it through gradle or manually through shell. Once installed to start the app, I have to run 2 through terminal.

**1. Install the app:**
gradle clean & gradle assembleDebug or adb install app-debug.apk

**2. Start the app:**
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n com.android.jdd.locationservices/.BootReceiver

So would it be possible to start the app internally rather then a separate command 2?

Thanks

Comment: If you are asking if it is possible to do this on production hardware for apps distributed through normal channels... no, it is not.

You seem to be focused on doing this as a developer. In that case, create yourself a Gradle task that depends on `installDebug` and runs your service (or sends that broadcast).

Comment: Its definitely not for production hardware. It's for personal use and installed on my local devices. Yes I was able to create a task(i.e. startApp) which is dependent on the installDebug and runs the service. But I would to get away from that and rather have adb install the service and start the service.

Comment: You already have that. It's in your question. What I assume you mean is that you want some *single* `adb` command to do that, and that does not exist.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I do understand that there isn't a single adb shell command that would combine 1 & 2 but is there a way programmatically start the service after install?

Comment: Use `adb shell am startservice`.

Comment: yeah that's using the shell. When phone gets restarted, I don't want to plug it back in and re start the services. It would be better to have itself start.

Comment: Your `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver can handle that, via `startService()`, assuming that your app has 1+ activities and that you have run one of those activities.